# Getting Duplicates in Clickhouse clustering

Tags: clickhouse

I have started clustering environment on clickhouse.

I have started with the basic two shard and one replica configuration using distrbuted table concept.

When i am executing the query on distributed table i am getting the duplicate values.

i.e. if i have 43 rows i am getting result as 86.

Can anyone please help how to solve this duplicates problem..

Please find my config.xml file settings below.  I have used same settings in both of my clickhouse servers

```
<http_port>8123</http_port>
    <tcp_port>9000</tcp_port>
<remote_servers>
    <perftest_3shards_1replicas>
        <shard>
            <replica>
                <host>192.168.0.132</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
            <replica>
                <host>192.168.0.184</host>
                <port>9000</port>
            </replica>
        </shard>
        <shard>
    </perftest_3shards_1replicas>
</remote_servers>
```

Comment: i met same issue, i found its caused by two cluster with same name! \(//∇//)\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood, you have just put same data to each shard instead of splitting the data between shards.